# Invoke Struts Action Test from within a web app (JSF managed bean): TestCase.fname cannot be null

Tags: spring, jsf, struts2, junit, struts

I have a Junit 3.8 test of a Struts 2 action that runs with no problems from my workspace (from eclipse: right click > run as > junit test).

For this, I use two plugins:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the test class:

```
package com.myapp.user.my;

import org.apache.struts2.StrutsSpringTestCase;

import com.myapp.user.action.UserAction;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxy;

public class TestAccountActionUsingStrutsTestCase extends StrutsSpringTestCase {

    public void testUserNameErrorMessage() throws Exception {

        request.setParameter("userBean.userName", "Bruc");
        request.setParameter("userBean.password", "test");

        ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/userAction");

        UserAction userAction = (UserAction) proxy.getAction();

        proxy.execute();

        assertTrue("Problem There were no errors present in fieldErrors but there should have been one error present", userAction.getFieldErrors().size() == 1);
        assertTrue("Problem field user.userName not present in fieldErrors but it should have been",
                userAction.getFieldErrors().containsKey("userBean.userName") );

        System.out.println("Finish 1 test.");
    }

}
```

Next, I try to **invoke this test, this time from within a web application (a JSF managed bean).**

Here is my code for trying to do that (I'm calling the following `runTest()` method from a managed bean):

```
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

import com.myapp.user.my.TestAccountActionUsingStrutsTestCase;

public class CallStrutsActionExecuteThruTest {

    public void runTest(){

        System.out.println("CallStrutsActionExecuteThruTest.runTest() is executed.");

        TestAccountActionUsingStrutsTestCase test = new TestAccountActionUsingStrutsTestCase();

        JUnitCore jUnitCore = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = jUnitCore.run(test);

        List<Failure> list = result.getFailures();

        for (Failure failure : list) {
            System.out.println(failure.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Test done!");
    }

}
```

When I access the managed bean, I can see that `runTest()` is called. The first output `CallStrutsActionExecuteThruTest.runTest() is executed.` is printed to console. Strangely, the next outputs are not printed to console, although the debugger shows me they are executed.

Also, `result.getFailures()` returns a list with one element. As I said, its `failure.getMessage()` for some reason is not printed to console, but when I watch it in the debugger its value is **`TestCase.fname cannot be null`**.

*** Even when I have only one method in my test class:

```
public void testTrue() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("inside testTrue().");

    assertTrue(true);
}
```

I still get the same results.

My questions are,

1. If I want to run the Struts action test from a JSF managed bean, am I using the Junit API correctly?
2. Why weren't the outputs that followed the first one printed to console?
3. How do I set `TestCase.fname` with a value? First I don't see a method in my test class to set this value. Second, from my understanding, `fanme` is the name of the test method in the test class that I want to call; and `jUnitCore.run(test)` should call all the test methods in the test class `test`, so how can I specify all these methods with only one `fname` parameter?

**Download** - you can download my project [here](http://www.filedropper.com/struts2-with-spring-di-integration-example-junit-from-ui). I use Maven, Eclipse, and deploy on Jboss 7.

I access the JSF managed bean by: `http://localhost:8080/Struts2WithSpringDIIntegrationExampleJunitFromUI-1.0-SNAPSHOT/xhtml/hello.jsf`

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 tests don't work with raw parameters for some reason. Use `parameterMap` instead.

```
Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
parameterMap.put("userBean.userName", new String[]{"Bruc"}); 
parameterMap.put("userBean.password", new String[]{"test"});
StrutsMockHttpServletRequest request = new StrutsMockHttpServletRequest();
request.setupGetServletPath("/userAction");
request.setParameterMap(parameterMap);
```

Comment: Is this supposed to work with the plugins I've mentioned above? I do not have the `StrutsMockHttpServletRequest` that you are using on my current classpath. Where do I get it from? The 'request' my code uses is `org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest` that I'm getting built-in from the `struts2-junit-plugin`. If I override it with a different one I believe it will interfere with the operation of the plugin I'm using. Also, the test class I've mentioned above did work for me from the workspace (not from a webapp). Why do you say it won't work?

Comment: you can download my code here: http://www.filedropper.com/struts2-with-spring-di-integration-example-junit-from-ui

Comment: No, you are doing something wrong. Why do you want to run it from a JSF managed bean? Then ask why the output is not captured? Didn't posted the complete code and asking why the validation failed? Your question is too vague. Why do you want to run junit plugin, instead of running normal struts testcases?

Comment: My reason to running struts tests from JSF managed beans is: in a new JSF app I am trying to use legacy Struts actions (get the HTTP response they create, and trigger their writing to the DB). 1st way to do so is to copy the action logic into my JSF managed beans - this is very hard with this specific legacy app. 2nd way is what that I'm trying to do here. If you are aware of an alternative way, I would definitely be glad to hear.

Comment: It's hard to understand what do you mean legacy Struts actions. Is it Struts1 or Struts2? There's struts1 plugin that allows to run struts1 actions in the struts2. Managed beans are managed by whom, by spring? There's api in spring that is able to run proxies of struts1 actions. Why this JSF is no idea, may be better to ask some JSF guys?

Comment: The legacy app is built with Struts 2. JSF Managed beans are the JSF term for MVC controllers. Why JSF - since the new app I am writing is based on JSF. I think I can narrow down the problem to: do you know how to invoke a Struts action from a controller of another web framework? The problem is when the action proxy lives in a web container, not outside on a web container (which is the usual case for a Junit test).